Iban regex to find in text
I have a regex to find regex like following:
^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?[0-9]{4}\s?[0-9]{3}([a-zA-Z0-9]\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,4}\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,4}\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,4}\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,3})?$

This finds the iban like following:
DE89 3704 0044 0532 0130 00 ss
AT61 1904 3002 3457 3201
FR14 2004 1010 0505 0001 3
DE89370400440532013000
AT611904300234573201

but my iban numbers are in setences:
This is a cusotmer iban DE89 3704 0044 0532 0130 00 from somewhere

so it does not find the iban. how can I fix it?

Drop ^ and $ which are anchors for start and end of the strng: ^your_pattern$ to your_pattern

no it does not work

As you also allow letters and spaces, it is normal that also the letters of "from" are matched. Unless you require that letters in an IBAN are written in capitals, or some other restriction, you cannot do it like this. Just decide why "DE89 3704 0044 0532 0130 00 from som" is not a valid IBAN and then implement that rule.

what country type of IBAN are you trying to detect? they can have various lenghts as well as contain characters or mostly numbers.

\b[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}(?:[ ]?[A-Z0-9]{4}){4}(?!(?:[ ]?[A-Z0-9]){3})[A-Z0-9]{0,2}\b

@smoore4, that doesn't match lots of valid IBANs. For instance, it doesn't match IBANs that have less than 20 or more than 22 non-space characters. I guess you got this from some AI...

The first issue is that you have start-of-input (^) and end-of-input ($) assertions: you'll want to replace these with word-break assertions (\b).
Secondly, your regex tries to allow for a space between groups of four characters, but with [a-zA-Z0-9]{0,4} you also allow these groups to have fewer than four characters, even when they are not the last group. This makes it much more likely that the pattern will match a word that follows the IBAN. You can however design a pattern that will only allow the last group to be shorter than 4 characters (when there are spaces).
The \s pattern will also allow newline characters, which is actually not allowed in IBAN. Just use a standard space character instead.
Not a problem, but you could make your regex a bit shorter by removing a-z to only match uppercase letters, adding the RegexOptions.IgnoreCase option or prefixing your regex with the inline (?i) modifier. Also, [0-9] can be just \d. If you expect an IBAN to be in upper case (which is a quite common practice), you could make the regex less likely to match trailing characters that do not belong to the IBAN, like for instance XX99 1234 1234 1234 1234 from: according to the rules this would pass the validation when including also "from", but as "from" is clearly intended as a word of the surrounding sentence, it should better not be matched. With requiring only capitals you can counter such misinterpretations.
Here is the suggested regex:
\b[A-Z]{2}\d\d(?:(?: ?[A-Z\d]{4}){2,6} ?[A-Z\d]{3}|( ?[A-Z\d]{4}){3,7}(?: ?[A-Z\d]{1,2})?)\b

regex101
I'll leave it up to you whether you want to combine this with the IgnoreCase option.

I used https://regex101.com/ to try out myself and came up with a regex statement:
[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}\s?[0-9]{4}\s?[0-9]{4}\s?[0-9]{4}\s?[0-9]{4}\s?[0-9]{2}

The statement looks for an DE IBAN with optional white-spaces between its number blocks.
it matches DE89 3704 0044 0532 0130 00 as well as DE89370400440532013000.
It also detects the IBAN in your sample sentence
"this is a customer iban DE89 3704 0044 0532 0130 00 from somewhere"

However some of your Sample IBANs are not following the usual DE structure of 2 Letters and 18 following numbers. The regex will catch the first signs following that structure, for example it will also match DE89 3704 0044 0532 0130 00
from the "DE89 3704 0044 0532 0130 00 ss" sample in your input.
Also checking wikipedia international IBANs can have various lengths and contain letters or numbers after the country identifier so I think a general regex to catch all types will be hard do accomplish. Maybe multiple regex for different countries are the best option.

IBAN can have alphabetical characters as well. It is too strict to match digits. For instance, NL64ABNC0417164300 is a valid IBAN.

that is why im asking what type of IBAN is desired. German IBAN only has numbers for example, most of his sample input is that.

This answer is based on the Wikipedia article about IBAN.
Wikipedia article: International Bank Account Number
The end of an IBAN is alphanumeric so extract an IBAN in a sentence is not possible. But since each country’s IBAN has a fixed length, the string can be extracted based on the country code.
This is for the German IBAN.
DE\d{2}(?:\s*)(A-Za-z0-9){18}
The groups of four is not a requirement, only for readability. This regex allows for any type of grouping (intentionally or not) and whitespaces, including line feed, since it might occur in a sentence.
The following code contains regex for five countries and a test case. Just expand with other relevant countries. The changes are the first two characters with the country code and the last number which is the length of that country’s IBAN minus 4. The country code and length is from the Wikipedia article.
I have also included a validation code as described in the Wikipedia article. An extra check that the extracted IBAN is valid with high probability.
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

/* ================================================================
 * THIS CODE IS CREATED FOR THIS ANSWER AND NOT TESTED THOROUGHLY, 
 * ONLY TESTED WITH THE EXAMPLE IN THE WIKIPEDIA ARTICLE !!!
 * ================================================================
 */
string pattern = @"\b(DE\d{2}(?:\s*)([A-Za-z0-9](?:\s*)){18}
                    |FR\d{2}(?:\s*)([A-Za-z0-9](?:\s*)){23}
                    |GB\d{2}(?:\s*)([A-Za-z0-9](?:\s*)){18}
                    |NL\d{2}(?:\s*)([A-Za-z0-9](?:\s*)){14}
                    |AT\d{2}(?:\s*)([A-Za-z0-9](?:\s*)){16}
                    |ZZ\d{2}(?:\s*)([A-Za-z0-9](?:\s*)){30})";  //ZZ only for testing max value of an IBAN number

string text = @"This is the example from Wikipedia GB82 WEST 1234 5698 7654 32 
                and an invalid IBAN code: GB82 WEST 1234 5698 7654 3a checking the validation routine.
                Another example found NL64ABNC0417164300. Max test: ZZ59ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ";

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
    string iban = Regex.Replace(match.Value, @"\s*", ""); //Remove any white-spaces
    Console.WriteLine(iban);
    if (iban.Length > 4)
    {
        //THIS VALIDATION CODE IS BASED ON THE SUGGESTED ALGORITM IN THE WIKIPEDIA ARTICLE
        //Move the first four characters to the end and change all letters to upper case.
        string ibanRearrangedAndUpperCase = iban.Skip(4).Concat(iban.Take(4)).Aggregate("", (a, n) => a += n).ToUpper();
        //Replace all letters to a two digit value where A = 10, B = 11 ... Subtract Ascii-value from Ascii-value for 'A' and add 10.
        string ibanConvertedToNumeric = Regex.Replace(ibanRearrangedAndUpperCase, "[A-Z]", (c) => (((byte)(c.Value[0])) - ((byte)'A') + 10).ToString());
        //Calculate Mod 97 by dividing the "numeric iban number" into parts of 9 characters (first part) and 7 or 8 characters
        //depending on the string length of the resulting mod value. 
        int ibanPartIndex = 0;  //The current part's index into the "numeric iban number".
        int ibanPartLength = 9; //9 = first part
        int ibanPartMod = 0;
        string ibanPartModString = ""; //The mod value converted to string used as the first characters in the next part.
        string ibanPart = "";
        while (ibanConvertedToNumeric.Length > ibanPartIndex)
        {
            if (ibanPartIndex + ibanPartLength > ibanConvertedToNumeric.Length) //if end of string
                ibanPart = ibanPartModString + ibanConvertedToNumeric.Substring(ibanPartIndex);
            else
                ibanPart = ibanPartModString + ibanConvertedToNumeric.Substring(ibanPartIndex, ibanPartLength);
            ibanPartIndex += ibanPartLength; //next part
            ibanPartMod = (int.Parse(ibanPart) % 97);
            ibanPartModString = ibanPartMod.ToString();
            ibanPartLength = 9 - ibanPartModString.Length; // 7 or 8 depending on the string length of the mod value. 
        }
        Console.WriteLine("IBAN Check: " + (ibanPartMod == 1));
    }
}


Regexes are not the solution to all problems, just like in this case. Besides the BBAN patterns (that can be defined as Regex) they also follow
ISO 7064 MOD-97-10.
I would argue that you want to represent an IBAN as a (single) value object. A well documented implementation can be found at a library I contribute to: Qowaiv.
It supports code like the following:
var iban = InternationalBankAccountNumber.Parse("nl20ingb0001234567");

iban.Country; // Country.NL
iban.Length; // 18
iban.ToString("F"); // NL20 INGB 0001 2345 67
iban.ToString("H"); // NL20 INGB 0001 2345 67 (with non-breaking spaces).

More can be read here: github.com/Qowaiv.
